# node.js modules: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fpm/bin/iffront:49: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have followed the steps [here](https://www.codementor.io/javascript/tutorial/how-to-create-cross-platform-desktop-apps-with-nwjs) to create my first node.js desktop application, but I get this error after trying pack the application:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fpm/bin/iffront:49
var getRoot = () => {
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I get the same error when I run `$ fpm --help`.

I have installed fpm using `sudo npm install -g --save fpm`

This is the code at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fpm/bin/iffront:49`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

"use strict";

process.bin = process.title = 'iffront';

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var mout = require('mout');
var osenv = require('osenv');
var iffront = require('../lib');
var pkg = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json'));
var cli = require('../lib/util/cli');
var updateNotifier = require('update-notifier');
var colors = require('../lib/util/colors');

var options;
var command;
var commandFunc;
var notifier;

options = cli.readOptions({
    version: { type: Boolean, shorthand: 'v' }
});

if (options.version) {
    process.stdout.write(pkg.version + '\n');
    process.exit();
}

while (options.argv.remain.length) {
    command = options.argv.remain.join(' ');

    //Alias lookup
    if (iffront.abbreviations[command]) {
        command = iffront.abbreviations[command].replace(/\s/g, '.');
        break;
    }
    command = command.replace(/s/g, '.');
    // Direct lookup
    if (mout.object.has(iffront.commands, command)) {
        break;
    }
    options.argv.remain.pop();
}

// 在执行命令前，先判断是否有全局的安装包支持。
var getRoot = () => { //THIS IS THE LINE 49
  var platform = os.platform();
  var root;
  if (platform === 'win32') {
      root = path.parse(process.cwd()).root;
  } else {
      root = os.homedir();
  }
  return root;
};
```

Im on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You need a more recent version of Node (v4 or later).

Comment: @robertklep at this moment I have v.0.10.25, Do I need v4?? You know I have to go from 0.10 to 4?

Comment: Or use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), but that would be very slow. As suggested in the answer, `nvm` might also be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is arrow function of EcmaScript 6.
You need to update to latest version of node, or you could run the 0.10 version with --harmony flag.

Update: to update the node version, you could use nvm
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: `--harmony` on 0.10 won't fix this issue :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use more features of ES6, you should instead compile your code using [`babel`](http://babeljs.io/). As even Node v5.0.0 implements only 59% of ES6 features as of today.

Check this [link](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for ES6 compatibility table.